# Meteor - transfer data from API to Server to Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am struggling a bit with Meteor, i have this app that i would like to connect with an API client, which provides me a Secret API key, which i must not publish (in the client).

The thing is when i send the request, i get a JSON data, and i would like to pass this data to the client.

API > Server Call -> Client (Rendering).

But so far i have not come to a solution how can i do this.

I have a basic understanding how Meteor Works, but i have a good knowledge about JavaScript/NodeJS etc.

A little bit of help would really be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good use case for a client making a [call](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call) to a server-side [method](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods). The server can then use the secret key to make an [HTTP](http://docs.meteor.com/#http) request and send the result back to the client without exposing the key. Please note that your server-method **must** exist inside of a `server` directory to avoid inadvertently shipping the key to the client (see [Structuring your application](http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp)).

### client

```
Meteor.call('getApiResult', function(err, result) {
  if (result) {
    return console.log(result);
  }
});
```

### server

```
Meteor.methods({
  getApiResult: function() {
    var secret = 'abc123';
    try {
      var result = HTTP.get('http://example.com/', {params: {key: secret}});
      return result.data;
    } catch (_error) {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```